# syntax error in from clause. vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm getting syntax error in from clause in my vb.net softwware, can any one help me????

```
Private Sub txtSearchByDish_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtSearchByDish.TextChanged
    Try
        con = New OleDbConnection(cs)
        con.Open()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT DishName, I.Rate, SUM([Qty]) as ItemQuantity, BillDate, ( I.Rate * SUM([Qty])) As TotalAmount FROM Dish as I, RestaurantBillingInfo as P, RestaurantBillingItems as PD, WHERE DishName like '" & txtSearchByDish.Text & "%' order by DishName", con)
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        dgw.Rows.Clear()
        While (rdr.Read() = True)
            dgw.Rows.Add(rdr(0), rdr(1), rdr(2), rdr(3), rdr(4))
        End While
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: You're not specifying for which table `DishName` column belongs to and using additional comma before `WHERE` clause. If you feel there are relationships between tables, use `JOIN` clause.

Comment: Beside your error, your sql will produce A * B * C rows. Are you sure you don't have any relationship between them?

Comment: There's relationship between them YES, so whats your suggestion to solve my problem please help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't end your `FROM` clause with a comma.

Change `RestaurantBillingItems as PD, WHERE`

To `RestaurantBillingItems as PD WHERE`

Note that your program is your program is vulnerable to SQL injection

Also note you're using aggregates and are not grouping by `BillDate`, `DishName` and `I.Rate` and they're not aggregates. You probably want to either use aggregates for them, or group by them, e.g. `GROUP BY BillDate, DishName, I.Rate`

Comment: Thank you Erik von Asmuth, its working now however when i search something its showing multiplicated value, hope you understand me.

Comment: That's because of what Krish KM said. You better ask that in a separate question, and include things like sample data from all relevant tables, and expected results

Comment: There's relationship between them YES, so whats your suggestion to solve my problem please help??